Recent Community activity
Recently (2012 10 23) our Community bot seems to have dug out about 10 questions to the front of the SE. Does anyone know the reason for that?

The 'Community' user will periodically poke old, unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention and have a better chance of being answered.
From the 'about me' description:

Hi, I'm not really a person.
I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
I do things like

Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
Own suggested edits from anonymous users


(emphasis mine)

Well, some of those questions were answered as far as I know - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5061/323 , http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2293/323
